# Changing my Domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a function which returns a user's name in Active Directory for an Intranet application:

```
public string GetCurrentUsersName()
    {
        //Get the username and domain information
        string user = Environment.UserName;
        string domainName = Environment.UserDomainName;

        //Set the correct format for the AD query and filter
        string ldapQueryFormat = @"LDAP://" + domainName + ".com/DC=" + domainName + ",DC=com";
        string queryFilterFormat = @"(&(samAccountName=" + user + ")(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";

        SearchResult result = null;
        using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(ldapQueryFormat))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root))
            {
                searcher.Filter = queryFilterFormat;
                SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();

                result = (results.Count != 0) ? results[0] : null;
            }
        }

        //Get the email property from AD
        string name = result.Properties["displayName"][0] as string;
        return name;
    }
```

I've recently changed domain from mycompany.com to mycompany.local . I now receive an error whenever I try to run this method, should I change something? string domainName used to equal mycompany, but now it is equal to myco as thats the domain name I use.

The error I receive is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server is not operational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you recently changed domain from mycompany.com to mycompany.local the correct format for the AD query and filter should be like :

```
//Set the correct format for the AD query and filter
string ldapQueryFormat = @"LDAP://" + domainName + ".local/DC=" + domainName + ",DC=local";
```

Replacing 'Com' with 'local'

Comment: You're right, this worked but as my server is still on the old domain, a double-hop issue occurred so i've had  to wrap my code with:             using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
            { //my code }

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to build the domain string dynamically? Will it be different for different users or situations? If not, why not define it as a configuration setting? You can get the LDAP address for your domain from Active Directory, and then you just need to set a static setting in your website's web.config file. A domain name should change so infrequently that having it as a setting is easier than trying to dynamically build it.